# Why running procerdure very very slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[PSI]
    @`PartNo` nvarchar (50),
    @Customer nvarchar (50),
    @Date1 Date,
    @Date2 Date
AS

Begin
      declare @Qty int,
                  @i int,
                  @max_i int,
                  @b nvarchar(15),
                  @j int,
                  @max_j int

      IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.sysobjects WHERE name like '#Test%')
            DROP TABLE #Test


      create table #Test(
            IDX         int identity(1,1), 
            Item      nvarchar(50)
          )   

      insert into #Test(Item) select distinct Name_Customer from Master_Products where Name like '%' + @PartNo + '%' and Customer like '%' + @Customer + '%'

      set @i=0
      set @max_i=DATEDIFF(day, @Date1, @Date2)

      Set @Qty=2
      DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(200)
      DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(200)
     DECLARE @x int
     DECLARE @y int
     DECLARE @z int
      while @i<=@max_i

      begin
        set @j=1
        set @max_j=(SELECT MAX(IDX) FROM #Test)
     Set @b=Dateadd(day,@i,@Date1)
     Set @SQL='alter table #Test
    add [' + cast(@b AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']' + + 'int'
    exec [sp_executesql] @sql  WITH RECOMPILE 
    while @j<=@max_j
    Begin
    Set @x=(SELECT SUM(Qty) 
    FROM Planning_Stock_Balance 
    WHERE DateAjust<=@b and (select top 1 name from Master_Products where Name=Planning_Stock_Balance.PartNo) =(select item from #Test where IDX=@j)) 
    Set @y=(SELECT SUM(OKQTY) FROM Injection_Daily_Result WHERE PRODATE<=@b and (select top 1 name from Master_Products where Name=Injection_Daily_Result.PartNo)=(select item from #Test where IDX=@j))
    Set @z=(SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM Sales_PO WHERE DeliDate<=@b and (select top 1 name from Master_Products where Name=Sales_PO.ItemCode)=(select item from #Test where IDX=@j))

    Set @SQL1 ='update #Test 
    set [' + cast(@b AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ']=' + CAST(isnull(@x,0)+isnull(@y,0)-isnull(@z,0)
     AS NVARCHAR(10))
    + ' where idx =' + cast(@j as NVARCHAR(10)) +''

    exec [sp_executesql] @sql1  WITH RECOMPILE 

    SET @j=@j+1          
    end

    SET @i=@i+1          
    end

     Select * from #Test
     OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN )
    -- where Item like '%' + @PartNo + '%' and (select top 1 Customer from Master_Products where Name=Item) like '%' + @Customer +'%'
     IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Test', N'U') IS NOT NULL  
     drop table #Test 
End
```

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of the huge security vulnerability you have (SQL Injection), the. I would get rid of the `WHILE`. What have you tried to make it faster? Just posting code at us doesn't make a question.

Comment: I think the problem is isnull and while, but I haven't found a solution yet.
Thanks

Comment: `ISNULL` is the least of your problems in the above. YOu haven't explained anything about the above though, including it goals. Why do you need dynamic SQL? Why have you implemented a `WHILE`?

Comment: I want to create dynamic data fields for a period of time (one field per day), then update the data into each field, in the operator that contains null values. But when using isnull, the program runs very slowly

Comment: Then why not use a dynamic Pivot?

Comment: @BùiTuấn . . . The code is slow because you are using a `WHILE` loop where one is probably not necessary.  I would suggest that you ask a NEW question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

This code is quite obscure and it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

A few tips:

Use **meaningful variable names** eg `@stock_balance` instead of variables names like `@x`, `@y` etc. This lack of **naming conventions** makes the code difficult to follow not only for outsiders but for you too.

Normally, in a properly-designed relational DB, you will handle a customer by **ID**, or some **unique** key not by name like you are doing here:

```
and Customer like '%' + @Customer + '%'
```

That is quite **unsafe**: just think what happens if you have more than one customer with the same name, or a similar name.

Not to mention that such a `where` clause will not be able to use **indexes**, assuming you even have one.

If you display the **execution plan** while running your procedure it should show you the parts that are taking a long time (or you could simply add some `print getdate()` in your code).

Dynamic SQL is not only dangerous but seldom justified. There must be a better way of doing it.

You are using a number of tables in your procedure, the structure of which is unknown. What you should do is post the **structure** of those tables, show some sample data, and provide an example of intended result.